# How to remove white annotations from image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I try to remove the white annotations of this image (the numbers and arrows), as well as the black grid, with MATLAB:

[image: raw image]

I tried to compute, for each pixel, the mode of neighbors, but this process is very slow and I get poor results.

How can I obtain an image like this one?

[image: result image]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: How do you have the matrix in Matlab? Is it an indexed image (2D array) or a 3D array?

Comment: I got a 3D array with this form,
 
I = imread('raw_image.png');
[lines cols color]=size(I);

and i go for each pixel in each R, G, B arrays try to find the pixel with value >=220 , then if it is true i change the value with the mode of their neighbors, but the result tha i got is very bad.

Comment: Maybe you should increase the neighbourhood size? 5x5 instead of 3x3?

Comment: Also, are you excluding the white pixels from the mode computation? Anyway, to get more focused help you should post (the relevant part of) your code

Comment: Why mode? Did you try median? It’s a lot more common, and likely will give you better results. As Luis said, exclude the white pixels from the calculation. In that case you could even use the mean, which is even faster to compute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general name for such a task is inpainting. If you search for that you will find better methods than what I'm showing here. This is no more than a proof of concept. I'm using [DIPimage 3](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/) (because I'm an author and it's easy for me to use).

First we need to create a mask for the regions that we want to remove (inpaint). It is easy to find pixels where all three channels have a high value (white) or a low value (black):

```
img = readim('https://i.stack.imgur.com/16r9N.png');

% Find a mask for the areas to remove
whitemask = min(img,'tensor') > 50;
blackmask = max(img,'tensor') < 30;
mask = whitemask | blackmask;
```

This mask doesn't capture all of the black grid, if we increase the threshold we will also remove the dark region of sea off the coast of Spain. And it also captures the white outline of the coasts. We can do a little bit better than this with some additional filtering:

```
% Find a mask for the areas to remove
whitemask = min(img,'tensor') > 50;
whitemask = whitemask - pathopening(whitemask,50);
blackmask = max(img,'tensor');
blackmask2 = blackmask < 80;
blackmask2 = blackmask2 - areaopening(blackmask2,6);
blackmask = blackmask < 30 | blackmask2;
mask = whitemask | blackmask;
```

This produces the following mask:

[image: mask]

Still far from perfect, but a good start for our proof of concept.

One simple inpainting method uses normalized convolution: using the inverse of the mask we made, convolve the image multiplied by the mask, and convolve the mask separately. The ratio of these two results is a smoothed image that doesn't take the masked pixels into account. Finally, we replace the pixels in the original image under the mask with the values from this normalized convolution:

```
% Solution 1: normalized convolution
smooth = gaussf(img * ~mask, 2) / gaussf(~mask, 2);
img(mask) = smooth(mask);
```

[image: output for solution 1]

An alternative solution applies a closing on the image multiplied by the mask (note that this multiplication makes the pixels we don't want completely black; the closing will spread the surrounding colors over the black areas):

```
% Solution 2: morphology
smooth = iterate('closing',img * ~mask, 13);
img(mask) = smooth(mask);
```

[image: output for solution 2]